# How to call simple Node.js script from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm trying to create a basic web application with SMS capability. However, I'm a bit stumped. I'm using Twilio's SMS service, but it utilizes Node.js. Obviously, you can run it with a terminal command such as "node send_text.js", but I'm trying to make the call to the send_text.js file without using the terminal command.

I understand that you can use Express to host your web application, but I'm not too sure how you would go about calling a Node.js file from javascript.

The following is the send_text.js file I would like to call from Javascript.

```
var twilio = require('twilio');

// Find your account sid and auth token in your Twilio account Console.
var client = new twilio('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID', 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');

// Send the text message.
client.messages.create({
  to: 'YOUR_NUMBER',
  from: 'YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER',
  body: 'Hello from Twilio!'
});
```

Essentially, I'll detect a change in data using Javascript, and when the change is detected, call the send_text.js file to send a text to the user.

EDIT:

I've tried my own basic implementation of using require, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Here's what I have in my index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="send_text.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="sendText()" value="run external javascript">
```

And when I try to call the send_text.js, which has the following, I do not get any text message sent:

```
function sendText()
{
var twilio = require('twilio');

// Find your account sid and auth token in your Twilio account Console.
var client = new twilio('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID', 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');

// Send the text message.
client.messages.create({
  to: 'YOUR_NUMBER',
  from: 'YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER',
  body: 'Hello from Twilio!'
});
}
```

However, the code does work if send_text.js has the following:

```
function sendText()
{
    alert("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: Do you mean calling an Express end point from the browser?

Comment: You could put your code into a function, [require](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) it from the file you want to use it in, and then call the function there. You should probably also read some basic node tutorials. Doing something like this is pretty fundamental to JS development.

Comment: Hi Cully, I've tried doing just that, however, it does not seem to work properly. Please check the edit I've made to the original post. Also, thank you for that, any tutorials you recommend?

Comment: @tobeydw That's not how you export/import/include code. You really should consider reading some javascript/node tutorials. These are fairly basic concepts in JS development that you will learn very early on if you walk through an introductory javascript tutorial or video series.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the child process in Nodejs to call a js script from another js file using  `childProcess.fork(filepath);`
according to the question I understood. should look something like this

```
let childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess.fork('./send_text.js);
```

for more information see

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing us is some example source code.  You can copy and paste the relevant parts directly into your Express app.

Comment: Wouldn't this serve better as a comment on the question?

Comment: @Cully I don't think so, because it is literally the answer to the question.  The confusion is that they have to execute this code externally.  I'm answering it by explaining that this isn't necessary.  Sometimes, answers really are that simple.

Comment: The reason I think this would work better as a comment is that you could include a few things to actually make this a valuable answer (eg. examples, references, etc.).

Comment: @Cully This person posted none of their code of their server, so there's nothing to say where to integrate it.  They obviously already know how to use this code.  They also know how to write the server code, since they're using Express.  It seems the confusion is simply that they don't know they can `require()` this or paste it right in.  You're welcome to write your own answer that meets your standards.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could use a tool like Netlify--here's a tutorial on how to [send text messages from a static website using Twilio, Netlify, and Serverless Functions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/a-how-to-send-text-messages-from-your-static-site-using-netlify-twilio-and-serverless-functions).

You could also use Twilio's serverless environment for web apps called [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions)--[here's a tutorial on that](https://www.twilio.com/blog/serverless-sms-messaging-javascript-twilio-functions) using the [Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart) as well.

Similarly, you could [send a SMS from a Gatsby website with Serverless Functions and React.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/sending-sms-gatsby-react-serverless), or use an [AWS Lambda Function to send a SMS](https://gist.github.com/stevebowman/7cff9dd80b227c899728).